# SQL RAND() function used to return a repeatable sample set result, but results changed?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, random

```
SELECT ITEMID FROM IMPORT_DOCUMENTS 
WHERE ITEMID IN(SELECT ITEM_ID FROM PUBLIC_FOLDER_DOCUMENTS WHERE FOLDER_ID = 96) 
AND (ABS(CAST((BINARY_CHECKSUM(*) * RAND(734014465)) as int))% 369279) < 506
```

Typically, we use `ORDER BY NEWID()` in SQL Server 2008 to obtain random samples, but in this case the client has requested we use a `RAND([seed])` function to obtain a sample that we can again replicate later.

The query above is what we used to generate one sample group.  We wanted to obtain about 500 rows from a group of 369,279 records.  (this explains the 369279 & 506 values)

We ran this early today and received 501 records, which is what we're looking for. We repeated these same results many times. Now, running this later we're receiving a different set of 527 records. My understanding is that this query's results would be static, but apparently not.  Can anyone explain how these results could have changed, given the query we have used?

Please note that the population defined by `FOLDER_ID = 96` has not changed in any way.

Thank you!

Comment: So, you're unhappy about the results of RAND() being random?

Comment: @mustaccio . . . The user is unhappy because the documented behavior of `rand()` returning the same result with a given seed is causing a problem.  I think this is a very good question.

Comment: Instead of relying on some random generation being consistent from execution to execution, why not - especially if the population doesn't change - you generate the random per-row values once, and store them? For example you could add a column to this table (or create a separate table with ITEM_ID as a key) and then the results will be predictable because you only generated the random coefficients once. Expecting this to generate the same results every time, when the result of BINARY_CHECKSUM will change every time any column in any row changes...

Comment: When you say "the population for FOLDER_ID=96 has not changed in any way", are you sure this is true in `IMPORT_DOCUMENTS`.  Even re-importing the same data could (conceivably) cause a difference to appear.

Comment: Thank you, storing the set is Plan B.  I guess a more specific question is: if the FOLDER_ID set never changes, what could have influenced the outcome of RAND() in this query?  The selection is being made from IMPORT_DOCUMENTS, but only a single column is involved.  Would adding an additional column or additional rows to the table affect the outcome?  I had assumed not, simply because the set of ITEMIDs from FOLDER_ID = 96 would remain static.  Is this my mistake?